# How to pass type parameter dynamically while creating an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net-core

Assuming I've got a class looking like the following one:

```
public class MyClass<MyType> : MyBaseClass<MyType> where MyType : class, IMyInterface
{
}
```

In a first step, I'm getting a List with all types of the classes that implement IMyInterface
var typeIMyInterface = typeof(IMyInterface);

```
var typesThatImplementIMyInterface = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                                 .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                                 .Where(p => typeIMyInterface .IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass);
```

Then in a second step, I want to loop through these types and create an instance of MyClass for the type in the loop fof further usage.

```
foreach (Type typeThatImplementsIMyInterface in typesThatImplementIMyInterface)
{
    var myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<MyClass<typeThatImplementsIMyInterface>>();
}
```

Unfortunately, the last block of code doesn't work because of a compile-time error "Cannot resolve type typeThatImplementsIMyInterface".

How can I pass this type correctly, so that I can successfully create an instance of the object?

Comment: you should use the ungeneric version of [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-reflection-bindingflags-system-reflection-binder-system-object()-system-globalization-cultureinfo-system-object())).

Comment: @HimBromBeere unfortunately this doesn't work either. Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass<typeThatImplementsIMyInterface>)); still returns the compile-time error "Cannot resolve type typeThatImplementsIMyInterface".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to construct the type using `Type.MakeGenericType` and afterwards call the un-generic version of `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
var d1 = typeof(MyClass<>);
var constructedType = d1.MakeGenericType(new[] { typeThatImplementsIMyInterface });
var instance = activator.CreateInstance(constructedType);
```